# If Cage and an Alpha died at the same moment which reset would take precedence?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow, all-you-need-is-kill

I am not sure if this is discussed in the comics, the movie or any of the literature that has come out since.

If Cage dies he resets the day back to before the invasion.

If an Alpha dies the Omega resets the day back to before the Alpha died.

So if Cage and an Alpha both died at the same moment, would the day reset to Cage's start, or would the Omega take precedence and reset the day to its designs.

Comment: I don't think we can be sure it's necessary for there to be only a single, "master" reset.  Multiple resets may be happening subjectively - Cage may be resetting on his own schedule, and the Alpha may be resetting on *its* own schedule.  As with all time travel tropes, it's all a handwave and probably can not be logically untangled.

Comment: Btw : In reality there is no such thing as an "exactly same moment". It all depends on the frame of reference. :-)

Comment: I was under the impression that there was only one reset button (that all Alphas share) and that Cage had managed to wrest it from the aliens.